# rails create polymorphic url with polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the basic setup:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, as: :documentable
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, as: :documentable
end
```

Now in _index.html.erb of my documents view, I want to do the following:

```
<%= link_to "New Document", polymorphic_path([:new, @documentable, Document.new]) %>
```

where @documentable will either be an instance of Contact or Case.

I expect the above to generate a url like new_contact_document_path, but instead it just tries to produce a url like new_documents_path.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to "New Document", new_polymorphic_path([@documentable, Document]) %>
```

Note two differences here from your posted code:

1. Use the "prefixed" polymorphic_path helper instead of embedding the new action inside the passed array
2. Use `Document` instead of `Document.new`, which seems to be the preferred approach

See [the ActionDispatch docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) for more details.

Comment: This also works for many nested routes: new_polymorphic_path([@model1, @model2, Model3 ])